# React-Native visibility filter won't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm currently trying to create a "TodoApp" using react-native and redux. I got the part where I can add and toggle different tasks working but I can't seem to get the visibility filter (show all/completed/active) in place.

Here's the relevant code of the TaskListContainer:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TaskListComponent from '../components/TaskListComponent';
import {visibilityFilters} from "../actions/actionTypes";

const getVisibleTodos = (tasks, filter) => {
switch (filter) {
    case visibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL:
        return tasks;
    case visibilityFilters.SHOW_COMPLETED:
        return tasks.filter(t => t.completed);
    case visibilityFilters.SHOW_ACTIVE:
        return tasks.filter(t => !t.completed);
    default:
        return null;
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    //tasks: !state.taskReducers ? [] : state.taskReducers
    tasks: getVisibleTodos(state.tasks, state.visibilityFilter)
};

};

const TaskListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(TaskListComponent);
export default TaskListContainer;
```

If the initial state is "SHOW_ALL" the app is working but whenever i add a new item it doesn't get displayed. If the state switches to "SHOW_COMPLETED" or "SHOW_ACTIVE" the app just crashes: "cannot read property 'filter' of undefined".

Every tutorial I've watched/read uses this "getVisibleTodos" function and it's working. Why wouldn't it for me?

Comment: its is easy to help if you can add your code to sandbox

Comment: can i do that with react-native? sorry if it's a stupid question I'm still relatively new to this

Comment: yeah i think you can.... use any other online editor if not sandbox see this:https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/rj6lzy69z4 I didn't get it to work, however you have all the code there, might give you an idea of whats going on

Comment: all your files looks empty and there is an error in src/index

Comment: yea, give me a second, i think it didn't save the changes

Comment: fixed it, indeed forgot to press save. don't mind the REMOVE_ONE_TASK action and reducer, its still a WIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i don't think there is a need to do that way i have moved it to `TaskListContainer` it is working fine as expected see here:https://codesandbox.io/s/1ok4k5vro3

Comment: that doesnt seem to be working for me. on the sandbox you gave here i can't add new items neither can i switch between filters

Comment: ohh sorry i gave the wrong url i think see the edited url https://codesandbox.io/s/1ok4k5vro3

Comment: thats seems to have solved it, so the main problem was that i was using `state.tasks`  instead of `state.taskReducers`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made a work-around this problem. Instead of putting the `getVisibleTodos` function inside the *Container* I put it inside the **Component**, filtering the data after fetching it from the store and not just fetching the ones i was using. It a bit more inefficient but it works.